# Do I have a claim for false promises by employer?

Tags: united-states, employment, labor-law

I am employed by the United States Postal Service.  I interviewed for a promotion.  Prior to accepting the promotion I negotiated a Salary increase of 10%.  When the promotion was processed I only received 8%.  The hiring manager confirmed via email that she had agreed tot he 10% raise. Do I have any claim of false promise by employer?

Comment: Does the hiring manager set the raises and did the manager say you for sure would or you were eligible for the raise?

Comment: The hiring manager does not set the raises.  There are pay schedules which are often used to determine standard raises however the selecting manager has the right to ask for more than the standard raise by completing a business case for a raise higher that the standard.  Raises may be up to 25% in a year.  The manager did not attempt to do a business case in this matter.  Based on my pay I would have been eligible for up to a 13% raise before I would have been over the salary scale for the position.  I asked for a 12% raise however agreed to a 10% raise prior to accepting the position.

Comment: Who makes the final call out of the schedules?

Comment: It would have to go to Headquarters and the manager of Compensation & Benefits would have the final determination.  It would go from the District, to the Area, then Postal HQ in DC.  That was to be done prior to the placement into the position.  I was never made aware there were any problems with the agreed upon raise until I got the paperwork processing me into the new position.  It should also be noted that other employees have been processed under different (previous) pay processes so they could get the agreed upon raise.

Comment: You say you were never aware there were any problems with the agreed upon raise, but you also say it goes through several steps. It sounds like the person you got the email from said he or she was agreeable to the raise, as in they wouldn't go against you, but you both knew it was not up to the person you talked to right?

Comment: No I thought it was completely within there control.  It always had been in the past that of the selecting official.  in the past 10% was standard and anything up to 20% had to be approved locally.  I was not made aware of this January 5, 2019 pay policy until this incident and was told that is why I did not receive the negotiate raise.  As stated there is evidence that the postal service has bypassed this new pay policy by processing some employees under a different promotional policy so that they could get the 10% raise which used to be standard.

Comment: Sry to keep asking you questions, but did the person you emailed say that sounds fine to them or did they say you would for sure get it?

Comment: Thank you I will continue to ask through our HR department.  We had negotiated over the phone due to me being away in DC at the time for training and she said I would get the 10%.  When it was not processed that way we communicated through email where again she stated I should receive the 10% and she would look into it.  That is when she came back with the new pay policy which she is stating she was unaware of.

Answer (score -1):

You need to identify whether the hiring manager had the authority or [implied authority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implied_authority) to promise you the raise. If he/she did, yes you should get the raise.

If the hiring manager has no say in raises or just said you are eligible for a 10% raise, then no.

Comment: This answer is incomplete as it fails to consider the principle of apparent authority. In nearly all situations, a hiring manager will be deemed to have apparent authority to negotiate wages with new hires based on their position within the agency/company/organization.